# UIView block animation transitions with animated content on showing/hiding keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview, keyboard

In my app I have a text field on some view which is covered by the keyboard when it shows up. So I have to scroll the view (or even rearrange the subviews). To do this I:

1. register for keyboard notifications:

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveViewUp)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                         object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveViewDown)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                         object:nil];
   ```
2. upon receiving a notification, move the view using block animations like this:

   ```
   - (void)moveViewUp {
       void (^animations)(void) = nil;
       oldViewFrame = self.view.frame;
       animations = ^{
           CGRect newViewFrame = oldViewFrame;
           newViewFrame.origin.y -= kViewOffset;
           self.view.frame = newViewFrame;
       };
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
               animations:animations];

   }

   - (void)moveViewDown {
       void (^animations)(void) = nil;
       animations = ^{
           self.view.frame = oldViewFrame;
       };
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
               animations:animations];

   }
   ```

This works fine, the view scrolls up and down, until I add some more animation. Specifically I'm adding a transition to a next view when the user taps a button:

```
- (IBAction)switchToNextView:(id)sender {
    // [self presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                        toView:self.nextView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil];
}
```

Now we got to the problem.
If the first view was shifted when the button was tapped (that means that the keyboard was visible), the transition to the next view starts simultaneously as the keyboard slides down, but the view itself **doesn't move down**, so for a split second we can actually see the underlying view. That's not right. When I present the next view modally (see the commented line) all animations go as I want them to: i.e. the keyboard is hiding, the view is flipping from right *and* scrolling down -- all at the same time. This would be fine, but the problem is that I actually don't have a `UIViewController` for that view. In fact I'm trying to simulate the modal behavior without `UIViewController` (why so? [perhaps it's just a bad design, I'll post another question on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720130/present-login-screen-on-app-startup)).

So why does in this case the animation from `moveViewDown` method is not triggered at the proper time?

### Update 1

I added a debug print to each function to check the order of calling, this is what I get:

```
-[KeyboardAnimationViewController moveViewUp]
__-[KeyboardAnimationViewController moveViewUp]_block_invoke_1 <-- scroll up animation
-[KeyboardAnimationViewController switchToNextView:]
-[KeyboardAnimationViewController moveViewDown]
__-[KeyboardAnimationViewController moveViewDown]_block_invoke_1 <-- scroll down animation
```

Even if I explicitly move the view down before the transition like this

```
- (IBAction)switchToNextView:(id)sender {
    // [self presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (self.view.frame.origin.x < 0)
        [self moveViewDown];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view
                        toView:self.nextView
                      duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    completion:nil];
}
```

I get *exactly* the same log.

### Update 2

I've experimented some more and made following conclusions:

1. If I call `moveViewDown` or `resignFirstResponder:` explicitly, the animation is postponed until the end of current run loop, when all pending animations actually start to play. Though the animation block logs to the console immediately -- **seems strange to me!**
2. The method `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`  (perhaps `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` too, didn't check this one) apparently makes a snapshot of the "from-view" and the "to-view" and creates an animation using these snapshots solely. Since the scrolling of the view is postponed, the snapshot is made when the view is still offset. The method somehow **disregards even the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option**.
3. I managed to get the desired effect using any of `animateWithDuration: ... completion:` methods. These methods seems to **disregard transition options** like `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight`.
4. The keyboard starts hiding (implicitly) and sends corresponding notification when `removeFromSuperview` is called.

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: I think, you are getting the keyboard down notification,when you are in-between your view animation.Both the animation may be conflicting with each other and the result is distorted view.

Comment: Just to make it clear: I do receive the notification in-between the view animation, however it **doesn't** make animations conflict or distort the view. I don't mind you upvoting, but @Jhaliya is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simulate the modal behavior without `UIViewController` I guess you want your next view to show up from the bottom of the screen right?. correct me if I am wrong.
If you want such an animation you can try a work-around where you change the frame of the next view within an `animation` block such that it appears as if its similar to `presentModalViewController`

Comment: Yeap, you're right. I could use `animateWithDuration:animations:` again and make _something like_ `self.nextView.origin.y = window.y` and then in the animation block `self.nextView.origin.y = 0` (of course this won't compile, consider it's pseudo-code). This is the default behavior of modal views, although there are other `UIModalTransitionStyle`s, including `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`. But it doesn't solve the problem and adds more complexity as well.

Comment: try calling the function with a delay that is after the view is animated down

Comment: sorry, my bad. You're correct. Please check the updated question, maybe you can add some other considerations.