# Present login screen on app startup

Tags: iphone, delegates, authentication, modal-dialog

In my previous [question on UIView animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719312/uiview-block-transitions-on-showing-hiding-keyboard) I mentioned that I have to simulate the modal behavior for some view. Here I'll explain why and ask about some better solution.

The first view a user should see in my app is the login screen. Upon successful authentication the program checks if the user is a parent or a child (in a family). For each of these roles the app must provide different functionality.

So I designed the app like this:

- Declare outlets for the login view controller and a tab bar controller (for the main part of the interface) in my AppDelegate.
- In the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

  - Set the `rootViewController` of the main window to the login view controller.
  - Make AppDelegate the delegate for the login controller, so it can send notification when it's done its job.
- When AppDelegate receives the message on successful login, it determines whether the user is a parent or a child, instantiates the set of view controllers that provide corresponding functionality and passes them to the tab bar controller.
- At last AppDelegate switches the `rootViewController` of the main window to the tab bar controller.
- Certainly the user can logout, then the `rootViewController` is switched back again to the login controller.

I would like to present and dismiss the login screen as if it is a modal view, but AppDelegate only has a bare window, thus I don't have an object to send `presentModalViewController:` to. This brings up a question:

*First of all, is it a good design?

And if it is, how do I simulate a modal behavior correctly?*

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.
However, I always try to get out of the app delegate as soon as I can, leaving it only to do application-level things (like respond to notifications, go in and out of background).  In this case, doing so will help you.

In the appDelegate, create a new UIViewController class, something like "startUpController".
Add it's view to the app window.
Then in your startUpController, do everything that you used to do in the app delegate (login, tab bar setup, etc.).
And now, since you're in a view controller, you can presentModalViewController to your hearts content.

Comment: 1. In general I agree with the first part of your answer. You've described what the application delegate is intended for. However there are some exceptions when the app delegate is used for other purposes (and becomes an app controller if you wish) E.g. the Core Data template that put its stack into the app delegate.
 2. On the other hand, a view controller is supposed to control its view. The view of `startUpController` would be no more than a dummy. Thus we'll have a 'pure container' view inside another container view (the window). This violates Occam's razor principle.

Comment: Well, many of apple's example projects put logic in the app delegate, but that doesn't make it right.  And if you've built any core data apps you've no doubt found how awkward it is inside the app delegate.  2. Feel free to factor out the extra view (or slice it out with your razor); Since you were asking how to simulate a modal dialog, I concluded that you didn't understand views all that well, and gave you a simple solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand views well enough, so I'm trying to reason logically. Think of it this way: if you don't have any login screens and different roles, would you create a view controller to setup the main tab bar controller?

Comment: (In your case I'd do it so you'll have a viewConroller with which you can push a modal dialog).  In most cases, yes I would set up a VC to house the tabbar. The guideline I try to follow is "a class should do one thing well".  This helps a lot when you want to re-use classes in other projects, or even within a project.  Finally, there is nothing wrong with dummy views (I call them wrapper views) as they often provide more precise presentation control, and allow you to stay in the class dealing only with local variables without having to call out to the appDelegate or other one-off hacks.

Comment: @mike, I've just found an interesting blog post. It says that [building any style of container view controllers is not recommended](http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited). Unfortunately, it's not the Apple docs or something equally authoritative and there are no arguments for such point of view.

Comment: @adubr - I'm not suggesting you create a container view **controller**, I'm suggesting that a contain **view** is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hii,

you should refer this

http://code.google.com/p/tweetero/

https://github.com/jbrien/WordPress-iPhone

Hope this helps!